# O que define o nome da arrow function no React

Tags: javascript, react, ecmascript-6

Estou estudando ReactJS, e no curso que estou fazendo o professor varia entre `class` e `arrow function`, a minha duvida é, da onde vem o nome da function?

---

Exemplo:

Quando criamos um componente no react utilizando **classe** a gente define da seguinte forma

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Componente extends Component {
  render(){
     return(
        <div>
          <h1>Componente</h1>
        </div>
     )
  }

}

export default Componente;
```

Ai definimos ali no `export default` o nome do componente, e pra utilizar o componente usamos a tag dele `<Componente />`

**Arrow Function**

```js
import React from 'react';

export default props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Componente</h1>
  </div>
)
```

---

Mas quando criamos uma **arrow function** da onde vem esse nome pra usar na tag já que não definimos ele no `export default`?

Comment: Você informa o nome do componente ao utilizar `import NOME_DO_COMPONENTE from './component_file'`.

Comment: O nome definido na criação é irrelevante, o que importa é o nome definido na importação `import UmNomeQualquer from './MeuComponente;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso da utilização de arrow function, você está criando uma função anonima e a exportando.

Para utilizá-la, você pode importar com qualquer nome que preferir.

Por exemplo:

```
import Qualquer from './path-do-component';
```

e usar como tag:

```
<Qualquer />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Existem dois tipos diferentes de exportação, nomeados e padrão. Você pode ter várias exportações nomeadas por módulo, mas apenas uma exportação [...] padrão As exportações nomeadas são úteis para exportar vários valores. Durante a importação, é obrigatório usar o mesmo nome do objeto correspondente.Mas uma exportação padrão pode ser importada com qualquer nome.

```
   // module.js
   export default class {}
```

```
   // app.js
   import HelloWorld from 'module';
```

Você podem encontra mais exemplo consultando a documentação do 
[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Description)